# My row takes up too much height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Im building a mock website and my css is quite rusty. My row in my container is taking up a lot of height. In my second row I want its position just below that row but it ends up on the end of the page. How can I fix this?

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container-fluid {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.desk {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 70vh;
}

.book {
  flex-direction: flex-start;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vh;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.search {
  padding-left: 75vw;
  bottom: 65vh;
}

.popular {
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="./images/desk.png" class="desk">
      <div class="col book">
        <img src="./images/book.png" class="book">
        <h1 class="logo">Etomon</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col search">
        <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Search?">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <form>
          subject/course <br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Graphic Design"> <br> level <br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Intermediate"> <br> starting <br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"> <br> ending <br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyy"> <br>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <h1 class="popular">Most Popular Subjects</h1>
    </div>
```

[image: This is what I am trying to recreate]
[image: second half of page]

Is there a way to control the height within bootstrap or am I doing something wrong with how my html and css are laid out?

Comment: Your not really having a grid. Read here about the bootstrap grid. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options

Comment: The height of `.desk` is 70% of viewport height (`70vh`) so that's going to take up a lot of height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap rows are designed to work in conjunction with columns. So, if you put an item into a Bootstrap `row` but not into a `col` inside that row or if you don't have a `col` inside that row at all, that will inevitably mess things up.

Oh, and everything you are trying to do, can be done with native Bootstrap classes alone. Without the use of any custom css.

Here's a snippet that should guide you in the right direction using a jumbotron in this case because I thought it was the most fitting:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    #hero {
        background: url("https://picsum.photos/1280/710") no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>


<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="hero">
    <div class="container">
<!--
        <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
        <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-7 mb-4 book">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/180/120" class="book">
                <h1 class="logo h2 text-light" style="margin-top: -50px;">Etomon</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col search">
                <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Search?">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                <form>
                    subject/course <br>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Graphic Design"> <br> level <br>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Intermediate"> <br> starting <br>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"> <br> ending <br>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyy"> <br>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1 class="popular text-center">Most Popular Subjects</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: P.S. If you explain what layout you actually want to achieve I could show an example how to do that with native Bootstrap classes alone.

Comment: I added an image of what I am trying to recreate. I appreciate the guidance!

Comment: Hmm... so, the first image in your snippet is supposed to be the background image and the second is the one where the word "emoton" sits on?

Comment: Yea The issue I see in the inspect tool is where "most popular subjects" is suppose to be ends up way below the page. It shows that the row is taking up a certain height

Comment: Forget about that. If I am to avoid using custom css, I need to understand what layout you actually want. That's not very clear at the moment.

Comment: Is the desk.png supposed to be the background for the entire thing? Or what is it supposed to do?

Comment: I added an image to that shows the second half of what I am trying to recreate. You should be able to see what I am trying to do better. The desk.png is just suppose to be a background for the top portion.

Comment: Check out the snippet I just added and let me know what you think. Note: I'm only dealing the the upper part of your page in that code because that was your question.

Comment: And of course, if you wanted to, you could add `style="min-height: 70vh;"` to the jumbotron (first div).